# jquery creating repeteable inner divs dynamically

Tags: jquery

this is a little bit complicated question. I want to achieve the following behaviour (creating sections dynamically): I'm sending the whole example: E.g. I have parent div and child div inside this parrent. In each div can be some placed some controls (inputs, buttons,...). I have following requirements:

1. each section can be repeteable (i mean creating it dynamically) max times (maxRepetition)
2. sections can be nested inside another section (in this example there are only two levels of immersion: parent->child, but it can be also parent->child1->child2->...) and each of these sections must accept requirement 1.

I have spend a lot of time how to achieve this, but not sucesfully. If somebody can help me I will very gratefull.

```
<html><head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">     
</script>       

<style type="text/css">
      .border
      {
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:black; 
      }      
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="main">   
<div id="parent"> 
    <table class="border" width=300>
        <tbody>
            <tr>                    
                <td>
                    <span><input id="field1" type="text" width="100"></span>
                    <p>
                    <div id="child" >
                        <table class="border" width=200>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>                    
                                    <td>
                                        <span><input id="field2" type="text" width="100"></span>
                                        <p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>            
                    </div>  

                    <span id="addSection_child"  onClick="addSection('child', 2)">Add</span>
                    <span id="removeSection_child" onClick="removeSection('child', this)">Remove</span>

                    <p>     
                                                                                    </td>                                                                   
            </tr>         
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<span id="addSection_parent"  onClick="addSection('parent', 2)">Add</span>
<span id="removeSection_parent" onClick="removeSection('parent', this)">Remove</span>

</div>      

<script type="text/javascript">

   function addSection(layoutRowId, maxRepetition) 
   {    
        var parentDivId = $("#" + layoutRowId).parent().closest('div').attr("id");                                      
        var sectionCount = $("div#" + parentDivId + " div[id = " + layoutRowId + "]").length;   

        if (sectionCount > maxRepetition)       
            return;

        var layoutRowIdSelector = "#" + layoutRowId;
        $(layoutRowIdSelector).prepend('</p>').clone().insertAfter(layoutRowIdSelector);                    
   }


   function removeSection(layoutRowId, currentDiv) 
   {                            
        var parentDivId = $(currentDiv).parent().closest('div').attr("id");

        var sectionCount = $("div#" + parentDivId + " div[id ^= " + layoutRowId + "]").length;  

        if (sectionCount == 1)                              
            return;                     

        var sectionToBeRemovedId = $("#" + parentDivId + " div").filter(":last");

        sectionToBeRemovedId.remove();              
   }


</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I thought those times are gone when I see bloody nested layout tables with one cell all the time, but they somehow still survive. Kills my eyes. I need a vodka.

Comment: sorry, but i'm not html expert :( i have received this layout and i need to add the mentioned functionality there.

Comment: i agree with compressor, basically just write the basic html for your inner section/div then you can hide them if you want and just use jquery to copy the html and replicate. make sure you rename the id for each control etc via attr("id","newname") for each div/controls added.

Comment: @melaos my nick name is **miroprocessor** not **compressor** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of reading the html of sections you can make a template for parent section and a template for child section then adding action to get html of parent/child template with new IDs then append it to your page. like the following

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="parent1">
        <table class="border" width="300">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <input id="field1" type="text" width="100"></span>
                        <p>
                            <div id="child1">
                                <table class="border" width="200">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span>
                                                    <input id="field2" type="text" width="100"></span>
                                                <p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div> <span id="removeSection_child1" onclick="removeChildSection('1')">Remove child</span>
                            <p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span id="addSection_child1" name="addSection_child" onclick="addChildSection('1')">
                                Add child</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="childTemplate" style="display: none">
    <div id="child#index#">
        <table class="border" width="200">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <input id="field1#index#" type="text" width="100"></span>
                        <p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><span id="removeSection_child#index#" onclick="removeChildSection('#index#')">
            Remove child</span>
    </div>
    <span id="addSection_child#index#" name="addSection_child#index#" onclick="addChildSection('#parentIndex#')">
        Add child</span> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addChildSection(parentIndex) {
        var childTempHtml = $('#childTemplate').html();
        var newIndex = Guid();
        var newHtml = childTempHtml.replace(/#Index#/gi, newIndex);
        newHtml = newHtml.replace(/#parentIndex#/gi, parentIndex);

        var parent = $('#parent' + parentIndex);
        parent.append(newHtml);
    }
    function removeChildSection(index) {
        var childToDelete = $('#child' + index).remove();
        var removespan = $('#removeSection_child' + index).remove();
    }
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
    function Guid() {
        return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4());
    }
</script>
```

you may find the result doesn't like you want but you can use the same technique.

Comment: @zosim enojy :) but please before playing if it realy help you , check it as answer.